# wp_enqueue_style conditionally add for singular arra(posttype) only

Tags: wordpress, styles

I am trying to enqueue style for only certain post type using is_singular(array()) but when I define post type  static it works and when I add using get_option it doesn't works.

Here is my code.

```
// load front end scripts
function rm_scripts() {

    $types = new review_media_system;
    $ptpys = $types->rm_allow_types();

    echo $ptpys;

    if(!is_admin()){
       wp_enqueue_style('rm-stylesheet', RM_URL.'css/rm-style.css',null, 1);

       if(is_singular(array($ptpys))){
            wp_enqueue_style('rm-admin_gallery_css', RM_URL.'css/responsiveslides.css',null, 1);                    
       }
    }    

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rm_scripts');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add using get_option`'? I don't see `get_option` used anywhere in that block of code?

Comment: Oh that's in rm_allow_types() method. That method I am using at other area too and works fine but not here only.